# gsub not accepting fourth argument in gawk

Tags: awk

Have been using `gsub` when using `gawk`, but is not accepting the 4th argument.  How can I fix this so that I get a string without blanks ?

```
  for ( knam in tseq ) {
    ## Remove any blanks from array element astr[i]
    str = "" ; gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, "", astr[i], str)
    if ( knam == str ) {
      print "Matched line: " astr[i]
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least as of GNU Awk 5.1.0, the `gsub` function takes only 3 arguments, modifies the third argument *in place*, and returns the number of substitutions made.

If you want to assign the result to a *new* string and leave the input unmodified, you can use `gensub` instead

```
str = gensub(/[[:blank:]]/,"", "g", astr[i])
```

However note that while `gsub` is portable, `gensub` is a GNU awk extension - if you don't need the advanced features of `gensub` (such as back-substitution) then use `gsub` but assign the string first:

```
str = astr[i]; gsub(/[[:blank:]]+/, "", str)
```

See [The GNU Awk User's Guide: String-manipulation functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions).